# How to make an App name available for other developers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have uploaded app in Appstore with app name "ABCD".

Now i want to upload my app with other developer account due to some reason with this same name"ABCD"

So should i delete app first to upload in new account? Or Remove from sale option will work ?

I have enabled iCloud in that app so i can't transfer my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move your app to a new developer account, you can use the "transfer app" from iTunesConnect see [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f) for more detail.

If you want to only change the name you can simply change the name from iTunesConnect to the current app (with a new version) and than upload the new one with the old name.

Comment: Actually in my previous app is iCloud is enabled so i can't transfer my app.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not delete the existing app. You can simply transfer the app to new account and app will be continue working on your new developer account. Later you can update the new version on your new developer account.

Here is more details on how you can transfer the app : [Read more](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f)

**EDIT:**

As per your edited question, that you have iCloud enabled, then it is not possible to transfer the app.

**And if you will delete the application from Account A, then also the name will not be available on the Account B immediately. because the name was previously assigned to an App.**

You should try with little different name e.g **"ABCD Pro"**, instead of "ABCD"

OR

with some tagline along with name e.g **"ABCD - Let's learn together"**, instead of "ABCD"

OR

You will have to wait for a duration of 120 - 150 days, by that time the deleted name may be available to you for reuse.

Hope it helps!

Comment: if i upload new version of app in Account A and change name then it will app name will available ?

Comment: Not sure about that but I don't think that name will be quickly available for reuse. However, you should give it a try, if convenient. and if you do, then please share your results for others to follow the same in future.